# Displaying data with pagination using custom HTML and CSS

Tags: php, yii

Let's say I have a model that represents products in a catalog. The model supplies the content provider (`CActiveDataProvider`) to the view, which in turn uses it to display a grid (`CGridView`).

What I need is a custom way to display this data: custom next/previous page links, custom data presentation. Something along these lines:

```
<div class="pagination">
     <a class="arrows prev fl" href="#"><span class="icon"></span>back</a>
     <a class="arrows next fr" href="#">forward <span class="icon"></span></a>
</div>
<ul class="some class">
     <li class="item"><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="200"/></a></li>
     <li class="item"><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="200"/></a></li>
     <li class="item"><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="200"/></a></li>
     <li class="item"><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="200"/></a></li>
     <li class="item"><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="200"/></a></li>
     <li class="item"><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="200"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

What is the best way to do this? So far, I am considering the following:

1. Use `CGridView`, but somehow customize its output using parameters.
2. Create a class as a descendant of `CGridView` or even `CBaseListView` and put in the formatting logic in it.
3. Just do it the quick and dirty way: simply iterate over items and echo the HTML.

Or maybe I am missing something here and there's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own class to display this data as a descendant of `CWidget` class.
All the logic went into the `run` method.

Answer (score 1):

[Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com) is good for displaying tabular data. I use Yii with Bootstrap to generate my own data display, simply because I don't like Yii's CGridView, even though it's convenient.

Your controller function might look something like this:

```
public function actionList($offset=0){
            $model = new CatalogModel;
            $data = $model->listCatalogsItems($offset);
                    $this->render('list',array(
                            'model'=>$data,
                    ));
    }
```

and your model like this

```
public function listCatalogItems($offset=0) {
    $query = SELECT *
    FROM catalog
    WHERE <your conditions here> LIMIT 10 OFFSET " . $offset;
    $items = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)
        ->queryAll();
    return $items;
}
```

So with your next / previous page buttons, pass the OFFSET as a value in the url, ex http://yoursite.com/site/action/2

Hope that makes sense.